# Remove duplicate lines with a twist

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, uniq

Okay so I want remove duplicate lines but it's a bit more complicated than that..

I have a file named users.txt, example of file is:

```
 users:email@email.com
 users1:email@email.com
```

Now due to a bug in my system people were able to register with the same email as someone else, so I want to remove if lines have the same email more than once, example of issue:

```
 user:display:email@email.com
 user2:email@email.com
 user3:email@email.com
 user4:email@email.com
```

Notice how user, user2, user3, user4 all have the same email.. well I want to remove user2, user3, user4 but keep user.. or vice versa ( first one to be picked up by request ) remove any other lines containing same email..

so if

```
 email@email.com is in 20 lines remove 19
 spam@spam.com is in 555 lines remove 554
 and so fourth..
```

Comment: It looks like most lines are two fields; what is that `display` value doing there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This calls for Awk.  Since the field you want to check is the first field of each line, just reference `$1`.

```
awk -F: '! ($1 in seen) {print; seen[$1]}' users.txt
```

---

You can "golf" this to reduce it considerably:

```
awk -F: '!a[$1]++' users.txt
```

The longer form is more or less self-explanatory; you build an associative array using each email address as an index, without bothering to assign a value.  Then you can just check if the email address has been "seen" before (i.e., if the associative array has a particular email address as an index already), and print the whole line if not.

The shorter form is actually doing more or less the same thing, but requires more explanation for the shorter code.

The postfix `++` operator acts on a variable *after* the expression is evaluated, so we'll come back to that later.

In Awk, 0 means false and non-zero means true.  `!` is for negation and reverses the truth value.

Appearing as it does outside of curly brackets, the expression is interpreted as a boolean expression, with an associated action (in curly brackets) to be performed if the expression is true.  Since no action is explicitly stated, the default (implicit) action of printing the whole line is used, *if* the expression evaluates to true (non-zero).

Essentially, this retrieves the value in the associative array `a` which is pointed to be the email address (first field) as its index—or creates that value initialized as 0 if not already present, interprets a 0 as false or non-zero as true, *inverts* this truth value and prints the whole line if the result is "truthy," and then increments the value stored in the associative array at that point.

A common enough Awk idiom, actually, but I wouldn't fault you for using the longer more explicit version.  :)

Comment: there's only 2 columns I made a mistake one line sorry, also just tried what you said but it still outputs duplicate user emails :/

example

     
12345@yahoo.com:7841329

     12345@yahoo.com:asa123456

     12345@yahoo.com:9830023

     12345@yahoo.com:Jdhftgddtdi

     12345@yahoo.com:a12345678

     12345@yahoo.com:892000

12345@yahoo.com:28071976

12345@yahoo.com:9716

Comment: notice first column 12345@yahoo.com on lines

Comment: @yolo, which column has the email address?  [Update your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/348512/edit); I can't tell what's going on in your comment.  (Your original post shows the email in the *last* field of each line.)

Comment: emails in field 1 and user is field 2

Answer (score 2):

1. Use *GNU* [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) to group input by the *2nd* field, and keep only the first line of each grouping:

   ```
   datamash -t':' -g 2 rmdup 2 < users.txt
   ```
2. As a comment from *don_crissti* notes, `sort` can do it, but while it returns the desired results, it may also reorder the output:

   ```
   sort -t':' -k 2,2 -u users.txt
   ```

The above code assumes *users.txt* is sorted by the 2nd field, then the first field.

Comment: `datamash` will also "reorder" the output (because you have to sort first) unless your input is already sorted; sure, this is irrelevant as you can always restore the order regardless of the tool used to process the file

Comment: @don_crissti, If so, is that still the case with the `rmdup` version, and if so could you give an example input?   I've used `sed -n 's/:e/:ae/p' users.txt | sponge -a users.txt` to add a little variety to the input, and then tried `cat <(sed -n 's/:e/:o/p' foo) foo | sponge foo`, and find that `datamash` keeps the order, but `sort` does not.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Doesn't `datamash` require sorted input ? So, unless the input is _already sorted_ you will have to sort it and as a result the lines in the output may be reordered. I don't know what kind of example I should post... Maybe `rmdup` just works without the need to sort but in that case they should update the man page and specify that `rmdup` doesn't require sorted input.

Comment: I don't have access to `datamash` right now so my comment above may not make sense but as far as I can remember the man page was pretty clear that `datamash` expects the input to be sorted. If it works for you without the need to sort lines it means some OPS can and will work without having to sort the lines first.

Comment: @don_crissti, Thanks, for the clarifications.   Agreed that `man datamash` is insufficient, the [web page manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html) is better, but even that...  having to look under `-g` to learn why `printf 'a\t1\nb\t1\nc\t2\nd\t1\ne\t2\n' | datamash rmdup 2` only prints the `a` and `c` lines is just poor documentation.  But the functions are still handy...